# Flutter Streambuilder: hasData changes between false and true

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream-builder

I'm trying to check if an username is present in a document on Firebase.
I made this function that checks if the username is  `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo` and then it shows them in a ListView and the username is taken from a TextField.

The function actually works but if I open the page where the function is called it remains stuck in the loading animation and as soon as I write something in the TextField it loads correctly.

**What I tried:**

I tested with the debugger and while debugging if I wait before the `if (snapshot.hasData)` the issue isn't present.
I tried printing the value of `snapshot.hasData` before the if and I got the following log:

```
I/flutter (30489): false
I/flutter (30489): false
I/flutter (30489): true
I/flutter (30489): false
```

So I tried with a sleep just to test and with `sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 200));` it actually works but the animation is now broken.
With a sleep duration lower than 200 milliseconds the issue appear too.

**My code is the following:**

```dart
// when first opened the inUsername is "" but changing that does not matter
Widget searchUsernames(String inUsername) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .where("Username", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: inUsername)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      print(snapshot.hasData);
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Container(
          height: 500,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 100,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 2, 6, 2),
                            child: Container(
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                        image: NetworkImage(snapshot
                                            .data!.docs[index]
                                            .data()['Photo']), //account photo
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill))),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()['Username'],
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
      } else {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
    },
  );
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to [this article](https://ishouldgotosleep.com/hero-widget-working-only-when-going-back-in-flutter/) seems like I need to add an `initialData` to the StreamBuilder.

How can I add it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Within `StreamBuilder` you have to check not only for errors, but also whether the stream is currently waiting for data and display a progress indicator while it is loading:

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
  // handle stream error
  return ...;
}
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
  // return a progress indicator, for example:
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
}
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  // here you can be sure that the stream is not waiting and has data
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried it but didn't weoked, it's still stuck in that ```CircularProgressIndicator()```, as soon as I enter a letter in the ```TextField``` I use to take the user input the loading stops and it return the username lists.
I use a ```setState``` inside the textfield onchange to pass the textfield value

Comment: So it is stuck when search term is empty?

Comment: no, only the first time when the page is opened. It should return a list with all the usernames but instead it's infinite loading. 
For example if I enter a letter and then delete it leaving the textfield empty, the output will be a list with all the usernames, as it should be (the textfield is empty even at the start, if I start with a letter it still load with no end)

Comment: How do you call this searchUsernames function?

Comment: inside the build() like this https://katb.in/ibokeyucuta
 If I put the function directly inside the build() it works fine but I'll not be able to use the setState when the textfield changes

Comment: Have you tried putting the StreamBuillder to where you call the function, and use the member usernameToSearch that you set with SetState?

Comment: just tried, same behavior. The thing that is annoying me is that it only happen the first time it is built, when its rebuilt by setState this doesn't happens

Comment: And if you set initial value to empty string in initState?

Comment: I tried just declaring as String and even with https://katb.in/xuwozepuriz but same result.
It's like it's been called again after returning getting the data stream as in the console the output of ```snapshot.hasData``` is ```false
true
false
false
``` but if I wait manually with the debugger or with a sleep in the program it works fine and the output is only ```false 
true```

Comment: Well, sorry, I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help, have a good day!

Comment: Same to you, and if you find the solution, please share here, I am curious...

Comment: One last idea: what if you leave out the `where` clause from query when user name is empty?

Comment: Unfortunately same outcome

Comment: Hi, maybe I understood the issue thanks to [this article](https://ishouldgotosleep.com/hero-widget-working-only-when-going-back-in-flutter/) and I should set an ```initialData``` in the StreamBuilder. Can you help me declare it correctly? (if it is even possible to set in this case)

Comment: If you want to have all data initially, you have to load somewhere earlier all data, and set `initialData` accordingly, like a list of users.

Comment: So I should do a normal query for all the users without ```where``` and set that as ```initialData```. Isn't it an "useless" query like that?

Comment: Earlier you told that leaving out the `where` clause in case of empty user name does not solve the issue. `initialData` is used to have some kind of meaningful result until you get "real" data from your stream.

Comment: You're right, looking at the article he creates a ```StreamBuilder<String>(...)``` and pass in ```initialData``` a string, what can I try to add as in my case?